# Customize URL in AddThis

Tags: addthis

How can i access the URL generated in addthis and append a query string before it gets emailed to other persons?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From their site:

> To define the URL to share you do it in one of four ways. For our
>   newest tools, use the data-url and data-title parameters, like this:
>
> ```
> <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" 
>      data-url="THE URL" 
>      data-title="THE TITLE">
> </div>
> ```
>
> If the code you're using has the addthis_toolbox in it, use the
>   addthis:url and addthis:title parameters, like this:
>
> ```
> <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " 
>      addthis:url="THE URL" 
>      addthis:title="THE TITLE">
> ```
>
> or you can set it using the addthis_share variable, which will change
>   the URL and title shared for all the AddThis tools on the page:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
>     var addthis_share = {    
>         url: "THE URL"    
>         title: "THE TITLE" 
>    }
> </script>
> ```
>
> In any case, be sure to replace THE URL and THE TITLE with the URL and
>   title of the pages to share.